# My SearchView is unable to filter users in my chat application built with android studio when I make queries. It displays all app users regardless

Tags: android, firebase, searchview

My chat application has a fragment where all signed up users are displayed. I'm trying to add a search button that filters users that match a name or email that is typed in the text box in part or whole. However this isn't happening and all signed in users are displayed regardless. There are no run time errors though.

I'm not too sure what is wrong, so here is the code.

```
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query.trim())){
                    searchUsers(query);
                }
                else {
                    getAllUsers();
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query.trim())){
                    searchUsers(query);
                }
                else {
                    getAllUsers();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

```
private void searchUsers(String query) {

    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            usersList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                ModelUsers modelUsers = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelUsers.class);

                if (!modelUsers.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){

                    if ((modelUsers.getName().toLowerCase()).contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                            (modelUsers.getEmail().toLowerCase()).contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        usersList.add(modelUsers);

                    } else {

                    }


                }

                adapterUsers = new AdapterUsers(getActivity(), usersList);

                adapterUsers.notifyDataSetChanged();

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Besides that, if you consider at some point in time try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help.

Comment: When I type in the search text box it should display all account owners with matching email or names in part or full, However, It just shows all users, which is what is shown by default, before typing in the text box. However there are no errors

Comment: Are you looking for OR clase?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.